# Ruby try not handling exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following example ruby code:

```
def example_method(obj)
    ExampleClass.new(color1: @theme.try(obj['color1'].to_sym))
end
```

Which should pass either the `obj['color1']` as a symbol or nil to the class.

However if `color1` is not passed I get the error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_sym' for nil:NilClass`.

Shouldn't the try method be handling the exception?

---

Update: based on comments... I solved it by doing a ternary:

```
ExampleClass.new(color1: obj['color1'].present? ? @brand_theme.try(obj['color1'].try(:to_sym)) : nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write a helper method:

```
def theme_color(name)
  return unless name
  return unless @theme.respond_to?(name)
  @theme.public_send(name)
end

def example_method(obj)
  ExampleClass.new(color1: theme_color(obj['color1']))
end
```

`theme_color` returns `nil` if the argument is `nil`, i.e. `obj['color1']`. It also returns `nil` if `theme` does not respond to the given method. Otherwise, it invokes the method specified by `name`.

Note that `respond_to?` and `public_send` accept either a string or a symbol, so no `to_sym` is needed.

You could also define the helper method as an instance method of your `@theme` class:

```
class Theme
  def color(name)
    return unless name
    return unless respond_to?(name)
    public_send(name)
  end

  def red
    'FF0000'
  end
end

@theme = Theme.new
@theme.red            #=> "FF0000"
@theme.color(:red)    #=> "FF0000"
@theme.color('red')   #=> "FF0000"
@theme.color('green') #=> nil
@theme.color(nil)     #=> nil
```

And invoke it via:

```
def example_method(obj)
  ExampleClass.new(color1: @theme.color(obj['color1']))
end
```

Keep in mind that these approaches (using `public_send` or `try`) allow you to invoke arbitrary methods on your `@theme` object. It might be safer to keep the colors in a hash.

Answer (score 2):

The `try` is called on the `@theme` object. The nil error is thrown because `obj['color1']` returns nil and then `to_sym` is called on `nil`.

You'd have to alter the code to

```
 ExampleClass.new(color1: @theme.try(obj['color1'].try(:to_sym) || ''))
```

to catch that.

And then you would have to prettify the code.

How the prettification works will depend on the use case, so I can only offer some general pointer. One way would be to have a default value to [avoid having to deal with the null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern)

Instead of passing around nil, one simply returns a default value:

```
color_key = obj.fetch('color') { 'default_color' }.to_sym
ExampleClass.new(color1: @theme.send(color_key)))
```

This makes use of the [fetch method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) which enables returning a default value. That way you will always have a value defined.

Comment: Gives me the error `TypeError: nil is not a symbol nor a string`

Comment: In this example `obj['color1']` would be nil. So we'd be passing nil to the try.

Comment: So how do I handle when the obj I'm referencing is nil? but if present I want to call it as a symbol on the theme to pass to the class.

Comment: @Cameron, I proposed a prettification.

Comment: I don't think `obj` is a Hash. In fact, I'm pretty sure it is not.

Answer (score 2):

From comments:

> In this example `obj['color1']` would be nil. So we'd be passing nil to the try.

Yes, that's an error. You can't call a method with no name. *Technically*, you could avoid the error by doing `.try(obj['color'].to_s)`, but it's super-wrong.

I would check for presence explicitly and bail early if it's not there.

```
def example_method(obj)
  return unless obj['color1'].present?

  ExampleClass.new(color1: @theme.try(obj['color1']))
end
```

Comment: I can't bail. We pass multiple colors. Some are present and some are not hence why we do the try first.

Comment: @Cameron: yep, that is indeed better when you _have to_ return an example_class. That code can be prettified, but it should work.